# How to hide Swift Package Dependencies from Xcode Project Navigator?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a long list of SPM dependencies which I would like to hide because I my daily work with my project inside Xcode I don't need them.

So my question is, How to hide Swift Package Dependencies from Xcode Project Navigator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click this hide button

[image]

Which shows up when you mouse over the area.